# page not found when using slug url in django 2

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with slug URL .. when I use it and run the server it gives me that the page it's found

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', RestaurantListView.as_view()),
path(r'restaurant/^(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/$', SearchRestaurantListView.as_view()),
path('about', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html')),
path('contact', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html')),
]
```

here's the urls file

and this is the server

Comment: What's the url that's generating the 404?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `re_path` if you're going to use a regular expression in your url path.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', RestaurantListView.as_view()),
    re_path(r'restaurant/(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/$', SearchRestaurantListView.as_view()),
    path('about', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html')),
    path('contact', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html')),
]
```

Comment: There was a `^` in the middle of the `re_path`'s path. I've removed that. If that doesn't work, please let me know what the url that's generating the 404.

Comment: doesn't work, it's giving 'Page not found, Using the URLconf defined in muypicky.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
restaurant/(?P<slg>[\w-]+)/$
about
contact'

Comment: What URL are you browsing out to that causes the error?

Comment: restaurant/ this url